# Difference between Get-Help and /? in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

When I use the command `icacls /?` it shows me information about the command icacls but when I use the command `Get-Help icacls` it says command not found. This implies there is some difference between `/?` and `Get-Help` in powershell. But what is the difference?

Comment: icacls is not a Powershell cmdlet - it's icacls.exe. Only PS commands have PS help.

Comment: `Get-Command` can tell you the difference between a PowerShell cmdlet and an external application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Scepticalist and Jereon Mostert in comments, it turns out that `Get-Help` is used to get information about Powershell cmdlet where as, `/?` is used to get information about commands which are basically external executable files.

Comment: There is the help output by Windows command processor in language of Windows for the internal commands of `cmd.exe` on executing them with `/?` or using `help command`. For the external [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) which are executables in `%SystemRoot%\System32` with file extension `.exe` or `.com` the help is output on running them with `/?` in language of the executable (usually English) or if available in language of OS. For the latter also `help command` works like `help chcp`.

Comment: On running `help` in a command prompt window an incomplete list of Windows commands is output with a brief description. PowerShell command `Get-Help` works only for PowerShell cmdlet. [SS64](https://ss64.com/) offers detailed information for CMD and PowerShell for the Windows commands and PowerShell cmdlets.